# Is there anything wrong with injecting all of my actions into components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've set up my actions into my components like the following:

actionIndex.js

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import * as profileActions from './profileActions'
import * as uiActions from './uiActions'
import * as statusActions from './statusActions'
import * as searchActions from './searchActions'
import * as filterActions from './filterActions'


export default function bindActions(dispatch) {
  return (
    bindActionCreators({
      ...profileActions,
      ...uiActions,
      ...statusActions,
      ...filterActions,
      ...searchActions}, dispatch)
  )
}
```

SomeComponent.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import actions from '../../actions/actionIndex'

@connect(
  store => {return {...store}},
  dispatch => ({actions : actions(dispatch) })
)
export default class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
```

I'm in a prototyping phase and so i've been trying to set things up so I can work as quickly as possible without dealing with a bunch of boilerplate. Now I know passing all store data to every component is bad because it can cause a lot of unnecessary re-renders. Is it a problem to pass all actions to components similar to the above? This allows me to call any defined action by using `this.props.actions.someActions()` in a component, which is super easy, but are there any big performance tradeoffs? I haven't noticed any thus far, but i'm curious if anyone with a deeper understanding of react and redux has any insights. If it's not going to horrifically blow things up in the future I would love to just keep using this method.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the state / actions to their belongings. for instance, If you'd to develop a shopping cart, you would have for example `<Cart />` and `<Products />` and `<App />` to wrap everything up.

```
<App>          <--- Inject products && cart state + actions here?? 
 <Products />  <--- Inject products state + cartActions Here
 <Cart />      <--- Inject cart state + cart Actions Here
</App>
```

Although you can inject both `products` and `cart` state into `<App />` like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  redux: {
    products: state.products,
    cart: state.cart,
  },
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators({
    ...productsActions,
    ...cartActions,
  }, dispatch),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

Which is "easier" there are couple of setbacks

If `cart` state is updated, `<App />` is re-rendered. and re-rendering `<Products /> + <Cart />` not only `<Cart />` think about having 25 components coming down the `<App />` that would be something you highly want to avoid, 25 unnecessary re-renders.

Ideally would be to do the following:

```
import { funcionA, functionB, functionC } from '../actions'
```

bind only the functions the component will use. and connect the state parts for every container individually, only the state part that is used.. 
Al trough it depends on what you are bulding.

Comment: I understand the tradeoff with the state, and I mentioned that in my post. My example shows passing all state because that's how I do it when i'm prototyping a component. I clean it up to only pass the needed state when i'm done messing around. My question is specifically about passing all actions to a component.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem passing all actions into the `root` component as long as it's comfortable and easy for you to manage.

Comment: It seems a lot easier! Though you actually shared something I didn't consider. This is a subcomponent. If I put the same mapDispatchToProps on the root app component would it would cascade to all subcomponents? While that doesn't seem like a good idea, its interesting if it's possible.

Comment: @DigitalDisaster It would be available as `this.props.actions` you can then pass it down to children `<Children actions={this.props.actions} />`